# How do I save the files lists in vim?

Tags: vim

I've opened many files in vim,

is there a command to save the full paths of opened files into a separate file so that next time I can resume with `vim -p files.txt`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One quick way is to save the **[session](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:mksession)** with `:mksession list.vim`.
This will have lines of the form `badd +0 path/to/file`  (or +currentLine)
You can just pull out these lines if that is all you need.

The fun part is, you can resume next time with just `vim -S list.vim` `:-)`

More at [Vim Documentation on Sessions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_21.html#21.4), and many other web sources.